# How do I properly script CountA and paste the result?

Tags: worksheet-function

The following script works just fine for me...

```
Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()

Dim Filenames As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("B2").Select
Filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Filter (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(Filenames)
    Workbooks.Open Filenames(i)
    Range("E1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks.Open Filenames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem...Instead of "E1", I want CountA(E:E), but do not know how to get that to script properly and paste the result in the same manner as the above script, in reference to a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...I partially figured out my own problem with the following script...

```
Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()

Dim Filenames As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("B2").Select
Filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Excel Filter (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Open File(s)", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(Filenames)
    Workbooks.Open Filenames(i)
    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(C[-21])"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsm").Activate
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
    Workbooks.Open Filenames(i)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i
End Sub
```

It opens each file, from the list selected, selects and empty cell on the selected file (Z1), performs a COUNTA on Column E that is displayed in Z1 and Z1 is copied and pasted in the desired location.  Now, the problem is that it pauses every other cycle through the script.  Any ideas???